# Abelian Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the group $H$
 whose order is 55 ,$|H|=55$. Is it correct that each subgroup of $H$
is  abelian?? Why?

Comment: if $H$ is a subgroup, what are possible cardinalities of H?  Have you learned about [Lagrange's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29)?

Comment: Each *proper* subgroup is Abelian.

Comment: Please use LaTeX instead of embedding images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any proper subgroup $G$ of $H$ is such that $|G|$ divides $|H|$. So $|G|=5$ or $|G|=11$. A finite group with prime order is cyclical therefore abelian.

Comment: Or $1$ I think for a subgroup - no "proper" in the question. For a nonabelian group of order $55$ see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770913/to-construct-a-non-abelian-group-of-order-55-and-203

Comment: you're right even if the trivial subgroup is abelian. I never said the group with $55$ elements is abelian but I proved all his proper subgroups are (including the trivial one;-))

Comment: I hope I did't imply otherwise. The question is ambiguous.